# Error on commented line in ascx file

Tags: html, asp.net, comments

On a ascx file, I have something like this:

```
<!-- Some stuff -->

<h3 class="title_links title_fs">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="LitFileStructure" Text="something"/>
</h3>

<!-- I put this section in comment    

<div class="accordion">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptSubFile" OnItemDataBound="RptSubFile_ItemDataBound" />
</div>

-->

<!-- Some other stuff -->
```

I've got a control that is in comment but when I run the application, it gives me an error:

`The filename.ascx does not contain a definition for 'RptSubFile_ItemDataBound'`.

The code behind related to this control is also in comment. But, when I simply erase that code, there's no more error :

```
<!-- Some stuff -->

<h3 class="title_links title_fs">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="LitFileStructure" Text="something"/>
</h3>

<!-- Some other stuff -->
```

The compiler isn't suppose to interpret the code in comment, so I don't know how to explain that. I've got this kind of error a couple of times while working with asp.net. My guess is that's related to a deployment problem, but I'm not sure about that at all.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you cannot use HTML comments like that to comment out server controls, they will be interpreted regardless.  In addition to commenting it out, you could also remove the runat="server" attribute.  That way it will not run at all.

Comment: I just tested it without the `runat="server"` and it worked. Thanks for the answer. Also, I just found out the existence of [Server-side comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4acf8afk(v=vs.71).aspx)